# ActiveXObject creation error “ Automation server can't create object” on Windows 7

Tags: windows

I have a simple program called "test.js" with two lines code.

The content of test.js is:

```
var fso
fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
```

The command of running this program is :

> cscript test.js

If I run the program from 32-bit cmd prompt (c:\windows\sysWOW64\cmd.exe), it gave me an error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Automation server can't create object
```

However, if I run the program from 64-bit cmd prompt (c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe), it ran OK.

Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Borken registry kind of problem.  Use Regedit.exe to check if HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{0D43FE01-F093-11CF-8940-00A0C9054228}\InprocServer32 is still there.

Comment: It is there, and the value is c:\windows\system32\scrrun.dll

Comment: That's the 64-bit version.  Double-check that you are looking at the right key, Wow6432Node is the home of 32-bit components.  If that checks out then you found the problem, the correct path is c:\windows\syswow64\scrrun.dll.

Comment: Do you mean I should change the value into "c:\windows\SysWoW64\scrrun.dll" ?